# jQuery keeps resetting my datepicker field

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a form on Wordpress where a user can create a post and set a deadline. The deadline field uses jQuery's datepicker. All this information is then passed to a preview page.

I added the following jQuery code to restrict the range of dates the user can pick (currently 30 days from the current date). But when they preview the post, the deadline date disappears. It's almost like the jQuery causes it not to be passed to the preview stage or resets it somehow.

```
<script>
$( function() {
$( "#post_deadline" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "+30D" });
} );
</script>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I though the jQuery would only affect the date the user can select, not the passing of this data to the preview page.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `I though the jQuery would only affect the date the user can select` True! -- `But when they preview the post, the deadline date disappears.` The page certainly has reloaded... -- `It's almost like the jQuery causes it not to be passed to the preview stage.` That is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Louys. I've tried a bunch of things but I'm none the wiser. I thought the jQuery might have been running twice - on the form AND preview stage but that's not the case. It doesn't run in preview. I also tried running the jQuery only if the deadline field is empty. Still not working. Maddening how something that seems so simple can be so difficult. Can anyone point me in the right direction?